# How lock_guard<mutex> constructor can be compiled fine without mutex instance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am studying about threads in C++11 now, and I met the following line of code:

```
lock_guard<mutex> lg(mutex);
```

There is no variable `mutex`. `mutex` is only name of type.

Can anyone explain me how above line of code works?

Why compiler(GCC) doesn't print any error?

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void do_something()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(mutex);

    cout << "Working..." << endl;

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
}

int main()
{
    thread thd(do_something);
    thd.join();
}
```

Comment: What part of the code do you not understand?

Comment: Some more context might be good. For example, is the function part of a class where `mutex` is declared?

Comment: I would like to know how it is possible that I have no variable named `mutex` type `mutex` and I can compile code with this line. Is this line equal to `lock_guard<mutex> lg(mutex());`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler thinks this is a prototype function declaration:

```
lock_guard<mutex> lg(mutex);
```

To be clear, the compiler parses this as the declaration of a function named 'lg' which takes a mutex as a parameter and returns a lock_guard instance.

```
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(mutex);
    return 0;
}

vc12 output : warning C4930 : 'std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(std::mutex)' : prototyped function not called(was a variable definition intended ? )
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++ structure, class, enumeration and union names are in their own namespace (not a C++ `namespace`), which allows you to have variables with the same name as a structure.

For example:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    // Member...
};

SomeStruct SomeStruct;  // Valid declaration
```

---

As for you not getting an error, if the function you use the shown it in a member function, then it could be that the class has a member variable with the name `mutex`.

Comment: One serious WTF would be uttered if I ever came across this in a code review.

Comment: I completely forgot about this. Your answer reminded me. I think it's time for a refresher.

Comment: Very interesting fact, but I think the answer by @BrandonKohn is actually the right one.

Comment: I know I can create variable with the same name like type name. But what is going on in my line of code above? Variable `mutex` was created somewhere before and in constructor of `lock_guard` I use it? Or maybe in this line variable `mutex` is created? Or `lg(mutex)` is equivalent to `lg(mutex())`?

Comment: @Dakorn It has to be a variable created somewhere else, for example in a class. There is no instance created in the line you show. I still think you need to include more context, like the function the line is in, if it's a class member function and if so show the class with relevant declarations.

Comment: @Dakorn After seeing the code, it's definitely the answer by Brandon.